# Custom page template to sidebar/widget

Tags: page-template, sidebar

I have a custom page template and I want it to display as a sidebar.

How to do this? I google it but I did not find any articles/topics about this.

Or how can I create a shortcode for this custom page template?

Answer (score 1):

Use a shortcode include plugin and simply add a shortcode inside a text widget in the sidebar you'll be using on the widgets or customizer page.

**Here are some example plugins and how they work:**

[Include Me](https://wordpress.org/plugins/include-me/) -
`[includeme file=”filename.php”]`

[Custom Content Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-shortcode/) - `[load file=template/sidebar.html]`

[Insert Pages Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/) - `[insert page='{slug}|{id}' display='title|link|content|all|{custom-template.php}']`

[Include Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/include/) - `[include slug="hello-world"]`

---

You could also simply duplicate the template and rename it to sidebar-{pagename}

Duplicate page template, remove commented header inside the file, and rename it `sidebar-custom.php`.

Then just include that inside the other page template where you want to use it.

```
<?php get_sidebar ('custom'); ?>
```

---

***Other methods if you don't want to rename add another file just include it in your template like a sidebar:***

**(will return template-name.php)**

```
include ('template-name.php');
```

---

**(will return template-name.php)**

```
include(get_query_template('template-name'));
```

---

**(will return template-name.php)**

```
locate_template(template-name.php, true);
```

---

**(will return content-page.php)**

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
```